# Transfer Fault on SAME70 Xplained Microcontroller

Tags: exception, ide, embedded, microcontroller, microchip

I am using a SAME70 Xplained microcontroller for a project I am working on. I program it using an editor made by Microchip called MPLAB X. About a week ago, suddenly I could no longer upload any code to the board as I keep receiving the error

`java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: TransferFault`

Resetting the board, uploading different code or using other features in the program to interact with it do nothing. An important note is that when I got ahold of a brand new board of the same type and tried to upload to the board, it actually succeeded the first time. But then for some reason later the same error pops up again. It seems the issue is a bit more than downloading code as the function in the program which allow for uploading code or pausing the controller throw the same error. I have been struggling with this issue for over a week now and cannot use the board because of it. I cannot find any mention of this issue on the internet. Has anyone ever encountered this? Does anyone know the specifics of what a transfer fault is and can point me in the right direction?

Comment: +1.  Observing same issue, albeit on a SAME54 XPRO.  Switched to a factory fresh SAM54: same problem.  Plugged USB directly into PC (skipping the port extender): same problem.